# Wordpress Custom Post Types As Links

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I'm working on a plugin and I'm using wordpress' custom post type feature. Basically I'm creating a "Featured links" of sorts..so that you can add a link just as you'd add a post. User enters a title,  url (custom field) and sets a  featured image. The problem is, this creates a blank post for each link added. Using custom post types--is there anyway to set the capability_type to links or blogroll type?

Answer (score 1):

When creating custom post types with register_post_type, If you don't want to allow direct access to the post you could try setting public to false and then set query_var to true or your post type which i believe would allow you to still display the links but not allow direct access to the post. I haven't tested this though. I would have just put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you must use custom post types.

If you don't. Have you tried post formats?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
Andrew Nacin on [post formats](http://andrewnacin.com/2011/01/27/on-standardized-post-formats/)

---